# Given the number, find the row and the column?

Tags: matrices, number-theory

I have a matrix of size $n\times m$. I number its elements as follows:

\begin{align}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1        & 2        & \ldots  & m\\
m+1      & m+2      & \ldots  & 2m\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
(n-1)*m+1 & (n-1)*m+m & \ldots  & n*m
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Now, my question is: given the element number $x$ where $1 \leq x \leq nm$, find its row and its column. Can I find a general formula for this? I think that if I can write $x$ as $x=(i-1)*m+j$, then I am done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, whenever $1 \le x \le nm$ the relevant row can be found by rounding down $(x-1)/m$ to the nearest whole integer, while the column can be found by computing $(x-1) \pmod{m}$.